# Why does `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` then `mvn package` download more and different dependencies than just `mvn package`?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a java project using maven, which I'm going to build as part of building a docker image. To optimize the docker build process, I'd like to download dependencies in a separate step before compiling. So I end up with these two commands:

1. `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`
2. `mvn package`

My real use case has more parameters, but I've narrowed it down to just these two simple commands while troubleshooting this problem.

The first command downloads 1080 files from Maven Central. The second command, after the first command, downloads 232 more files.

The second command, by itself in a fresh environment, downloads 1080 files... but they only mostly match the 1080 that the first command would download, maybe 10% are different.

Here is the start of a diff between their outputs filtered for downloads and sorted, where `...12...log` is the two-step process and `...2...log` is just the second step alone, showing some common downloads and some unique to each process. Notice that in two cases, both processes download a pom but one downloads the matching jar and the other doesn't. In the first lines of the diff there's an example of a jar+pom pair that are downloaded by the two step process but not downloaded at all by the single step process.

```
--- download_simple_12_sort.log 2023-11-28 14:37:53
+++ download_simple_2_sort.log  2023-11-28 14:37:58
@@ -1,5 +1,3 @@
-https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
-https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.pom
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.pom
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
@@ -63,6 +61,7 @@
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-augmentedairuntime/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-augmentedairuntime-1.12.552.jar
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-augmentedairuntime/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-augmentedairuntime-1.12.552.pom
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.12.552.pom
+https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-autoscalingplans/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-autoscalingplans-1.12.552.jar
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-autoscalingplans/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-autoscalingplans-1.12.552.pom
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-backup/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-backup-1.12.552.jar
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-backup/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-backup-1.12.552.pom
@@ -589,6 +588,7 @@
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-workdocs/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-workdocs-1.12.552.pom
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-worklink/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-worklink-1.12.552.jar
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-worklink/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-worklink-1.12.552.pom
+https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-workmail/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-workmail-1.12.552.jar
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-workmail/1.12.552/aws-java-sdk-workmail-1.12.552.pom
```

I suspect the next step here would be to investigate the dependency tree to see what leads to the the exceptional downloads, but that's getting to the edge of my maven knowledge. So I'm asking here either how to proceed with troubleshooting, or what obvious situation(s) might lead to this outcome.

Comment: Maybe these are `test` or `provided` dependencies (even though these don't look like test dependencies). `mvn package` also runs tests while `dependency:copy-dependencies` doesn't.

Comment: `I'd like to download dependencies in a separate step before compiling. ` first why in separate step? If they are needed they will be downloaded why using dependency plugin for that?

Comment: By the way, you can use [`mvn dependency:go-offline`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) for downloading dependencies.

Comment: @khmarbaise when building a docker image, it is more efficient to separate steps that change frequently from those that don't. Earlier steps can be cached and not repeated on later runs.

Comment: @dan1st my real workflow, before reducing to a test case, had `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` but maybe it was still downloading test dependencies? I will investigate.

Comment: Can you run `mvn dependency:tree` and check how these dependencies are referenced? That command should also display the scopes of these dependencies. The dependencies might also be referenced by the some plugins themselves in which case `dependency:tree` would not necessarily show them. Anyways, I recommend `mvn dependency:go-offline` if you really want to make sure all necessary dependencies etc are downloaded.

Comment: @dan1st `mvn dependency:go-offline` downloads about 1850 files, 50-80% more than the amount needed to build and test. It also still leaves 25 files (9 jar+pom pairs, 7 just pom files) to be downloaded by `mvn package`.